# Error occurring while inserting and uploading file to remote server in php

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, upload

I have Admin Panel in which i am inserting data and uploading file and when i clicking on insert button it giving error like "*There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed*." I had uploaded my Admin Panel on remote server created in php Dreamweaver why its happaning i dont know please help. I wants to insert data and file upload on that server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<?php
include('header1.php');

?>
<!-- Javascript -->
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function() {
             //var currentDate = new Date();
            $( "#datepicker-7" ).datepicker({
               defaultDate:+9,
               dayNamesMin: [ "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat" ],
               duration: "slow",
               dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'

            });
            //$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", currentDate);
         });


function madeSelection(elem,helpermsg,e)
{
    if(elem.value=="---Select---")
    {
        alert(helpermsg);
        elem.focus();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;   
    }


}


function validateFileExtension(fld,FieldName) 
      {
       if(!/(\.txt|\.pdf)$/i.test(fld)) 
         {
           varError = varError + FieldName + "Invalid text file type.\n";
           return false;
          }
        return true;
       }

</script>
      </head>
      <body >
<?php
include('sidenav.php');
?>


 <div id="page-wrapper" >
 <div id="page-inner">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
 <?php
 if(isset($_GET['id']))
 {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
 echo"<h2>Update Product</h2>";
 }
 else
 {
    echo"<h2>Add Product</h2>";
 }   
?>    

            </div>
            </div>
             <!-- /. ROW  -->
             <hr />
             <div class="row"> 

                  <?php 

                   include('config.php');
                    if(isset($_GET['id']))
                    {
                        $id = $_GET['id'];
                        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                        {

                                echo"Upload Only PDf File"; 

                                $fileName=$_FILES["filepdf"]["name"];
                                $fileSize=$_FILES["filepdf"]["size"]/2024;
                                $fileType=$_FILES["filepdf"]["type"];   
                                $fileTmpName=$_FILES["filepdf"]["tmp_name"]; 


                            if($fileType=="application/pdf")
                            {
                                    if($fileSize<=200)
                                { 
                                    $random=rand(1111,9999);
                                    $newFileName=$random.$fileName;
                                    $uploadPath="testUpload/".$newFileName;

                                    if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$uploadPath))
                                {

                                    echo "Successful<BR>"; 
                                    echo "File Name :".$newFileName."<BR>"; 
                                    echo "File Size :".$fileSize." kb"."<BR>"; 
                                    echo "File Type :".$fileType."<BR>"; 
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo "Maximum upload file size limit is 200 kb";
                                }

                            }
                            else
                                {
                                        return false;
                                        echo "You can only upload a pdf file.";
                                } 

                                $updt=mysql_query("update product set pdf='$newFileName' where id='$id'");

                            }           
                            $updates = isset($_POST['updates']) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
                            $cat=$_POST['catnm'];
                            $prodnm=$_POST['prodnm'];
                            $prod_dtl=$_POST['prod_dtl'];


                            //$downld=$_POST['downld'];
                            $date=$_POST['date'];
                              if(isset($_POST['filepdf'])) { 

                            $query3=mysql_query("update product set catnm='$cat', prodnm='$prodnm',prod_dtl='$prod_dtl'
                            ,downld='$updates',date='$date' where id='$id'");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            $query3=mysql_query("update product set 


                          catnm='$cat',prodnm='$prodnm',prod_dtl='$prod_dtl'
                           ,downld='$updates',date='$date' where id='$id'");
                            }

                                if($query3||$updt)
                                {
                                    header('location:addProduct.php');
                                }

                         }


$query1=mysql_query("select * from product where id='$id'");
                            $query4=mysql_fetch_array($query1);
                            //echo "<pre>";
                            //print_r($query4);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                        {

                                echo"Upload Only PDf File"; 
                                $fileName=$_FILES["filepdf"]["name"];
                                $fileSize=$_FILES["filepdf"]["size"]/2024;
                                $fileType=$_FILES["filepdf"]["type"];   
                                $fileTmpName=$_FILES["filepdf"]["tmp_name"];  

                        if($fileType=="application/pdf")
                        {
                            if($fileSize<=200){

                        //New file name
                                $random=rand(1111,9999);
                                $newFileName=$random.$fileName;

                        //File upload path
                                $uploadPath="testUpload/".$newFileName;

                        //function for upload file



if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$uploadPath))
                                {
                                    echo "Successful<BR>"; 
                                    echo "File Name :".$newFileName."<BR>"; 


echo "File Size :".$fileSize." kb"."<BR>"; 
                                    echo "File Type :".$fileType."<BR>"; 
                                }
                                else
                                {


echo "Maximum upload file size limit is 200 kb";
                                }
                            }
                                else
                                {
                                        return false;
                                    echo "You can only upload a pdf file.";
                                }  


                                    echo "here downld";
                         $updates = isset($_POST['updates']) ? 'Yes' : 'No';

                                    $catnm=$_POST['catnm'];
                                    $prodnm=$_POST['prodnm'];
                                    $prod_dtl=$_POST['prod_dtl'];

                                    //$updates=$_POST['downld'];
                                    $date=$_POST['date'];

      $query=("insert into    product(catnm,prodnm,prod_dtl,pdf,downld,date)

 values('$catnm','$prodnm','$prod_dtl','$newFileName','$updates','$date')");
                                    $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);

                                    if($result)
                                    {
                                        header('location:addProduct.php');
                                    }
                                }

                        }
                        }


                  ?>

       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">      
                <div class="panel-body">
```

```
                <label>Select Category:</label>      
                <div class="form-group">
                  <?php

                        include('config.php');
                        $query1=mysql_query("select catnm from category");
                        ?>


                     <select class=form-control m-b-10 name=catnm id=catnm >
                        <?php
                         echo"<option>---Select---</option>";
                        while($query=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
                        {

                            $selectedCat = '';
                            if($query[catnm] == $query4['catnm'])
                            {
                                $selectedCat = "selected";
                            }



                             echo "<option value='$query[catnm]'
                             $selectedCat >$query[catnm]</option>"; 
                        }

                    ?>                                    
                    </select>



            <br/>                 
           <div class="form-group">


<input type="text" class="form-control" id="prodnm" placeholder="Product 
Name" name="prodnm" required value="<?php if(isset(
    $query4['prodnm'])){
    echo $query4['prodnm'];}?>"/>
           </div>

                 <div class="form-group">       
    <textarea class="form-control" id="catdtl" name="prod_dtl" 
    placeholder="Product Detail" "rows="10" cols="62" required><?php         
    if(isset($query4['prod_dtl'])){echo $query4['prod_dtl'];} ?></textarea>
        </div>        

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">PDF File</label>
        <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" accept="application/pdf" 
         name="filepdf" >   
         <?php if(isset($query4['pdf'])){
        echo $query4['pdf'];} ?>                        
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
        <input id="checkbox"  type="checkbox" name="updates" 
        <?php  if(isset($query4['downld'])) { if($query4['downld'] == 'Yes') 
        echo "checked='checked'"; echo $query4['downld'];} 
        ?> /> Is Downloadable <br />

        </label>
        </div>



        <input type="text" placeholder="Date of Upload" name="date" value="
        <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])){$id = $_GET['id'];echo 
        $query4['date'];}else{
       echo date('d/m/Y');>"id="datepicker-7">
         <div style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:40px;width:650px;">


<input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" 
onclick="madeSelection(document.getElementById('catnm'),'Please Select 
Category',event)" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['id'])){$id = 
$_GET['id'];echo"Update";}else{echo"Submit";}?>"/>
<input type="button" value="cancel" onclick="window.location='index.php'"/>                      

         <hr/>

         </form>



 </div>
                 <!-- /. ROW  -->
    </div>
             <!-- /. PAGE INNER  -->
            </div>
         <!-- /. PAGE WRAPPER  -->
        </div>











            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: What is the error you get ? And also do you have permissions on the remote server to upload?

Comment: Yes i have permission and which i had placed in double quote that is error occurring when inserting data .

Comment: "There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

Comment: can you put ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); in the start of your code so we can see the error

Comment: also, where is the submit form action pointing to ?

Comment: I had not put action in the form .I am doing it by  header('location:addProduct.php');

Comment: unless your html is in the same page, you need action on the form to point to your script.

Comment: action to which page ..?

Comment: is the html form in the same file with your php ?

Comment: Its running perfectly on local server wamp and easily uploading file in the folder but it giving error on remote server..

Comment: yes its on same page both html and php code..

Comment: can you dump the $_POST and $_FILES array ?

Comment: what? @Vasil Shaddix

Comment: need help i stopped here what to do.. getting error